Is this GURPS flaw balanced?
I’m not sure if this is balanced, thusly my question.

Flaw name: Bookworm
Effect: you must carry at least 2 books with you when you leave your residence unless its to get more books & even then you must make a will roll!

Now my question is this: Is it balanced? If not, how might it be balanced and any variations be possible in terms of strength?
It’s for 3rd edition and I’m not sure how much it should be worth myself (15 points?).
If the person with this flaw fails the will roll, they can try again after 10 minutes. They WILL also check to see if they have the required amount of books on their person, regardless of if they know they have them or not (oc/dc in non magical terms, curse in magical terms/medieval societies).
If they don’t have ANY books available to them, they will go into a 12 minute catatonic fit and then into a frenzy to find ANY reading material they can get their hands on!

This is improved because of the system tag-- thank you!  If you make the points cost a definite proposal with a definite number of points (instead of what it is now, halfway between asking how much and guessing a number) I am pretty sure it will be re-opened.  If that happens, I promise I will start the re-open process if no one else does it before I see it.

This is too costly at -15 points
If you look at the disadvantages that GURPS 3rd edition provides, most of them top out at about -15 points, unless they make your character dysfunctional like severe alcolholism or having only one arm (both cost -20). Most of them also affect you all the time.
This disadvantage is both easily mitigated, and highly situational. A small book does not weigh a lot, and unless you play a campaign in the deep middle ages, does cost a pittance. It is a trivial cost and hinderance to obtain two books and take them with you. It therefore should only provide a trival amount of negative points. The constant need to check that you added in revising the question is more of a hinderance, and the game has a disadvantage for that:

Compulsive Behaviour (-5 to -15 points)
You have a habit (usually, but not always, a vice) which you
feel compelled to indulge on a daily basis. You waste a good deal
of your time indulging your habit. [...]
The specific point value of the disadvantage
depends on what the behavior is, how much it costs, and
how much trouble it is likely to get the PC into.

There is little cost for Bookworm, and little trouble that checking your bag or pocket for your books will cause you. Therefore, the cost should be low. Yes, you might get some extreme behaviour if you lose your books, but these are fringe situations (and you can protect against them by stuffing extra pocket books into your boots for backup or whatnot).
Keep in mind that every negative point allows you to buy the same amount of positive power with the points freed up. 15 points will allow you to increase any of your basic attributes by a point to 14 or 15, or get you advantages like Danger Sense or Combat Reflexes that are useful in many, many situations.
This should likely not cost more than -5 points. At -15, it is a steal for unscroupulous min-maxers that are looking for disadvantages that do not really matter in play to boost their point budget.

even -5 seems too much, unless the state prosecutes possession of books - chain smoking has more impact than lugging around a pair of cheap pulp novels.

@Trish, I think it depends on how much hinderance the constant checking will be (which was not in the original description). If it is really obsessive, I might be in range. I do agree, if this is only perfunctory, sometimes mentioned, this would be worth less -- maybe just -1 or -2. In the rare cases where the loss effect triggers it could be impactful.
